# Where should I put my touchpad configuration file?

Tags: filesystem, touchpad

I am currently configuring my touchpad and noticed that I can put my Synaptics configuration file (`50-synaptics.conf`) in two different locations :

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

And

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

Both are working fine. Which one is better to use in this case? Or is this completely irrelevant ?

---

> `/etc/` is the nerve center of your system, it contains all system
>   related configuration files in here or in its sub-directories. A
>   "configuration file" is defined as a local file used to control the
>   operation of a program; it must be static and cannot be an executable
>   binary. - [TLDP.org](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/etc.html)

---

> `/usr` usually contains by far the largest share of data on a system.
>   It contains all the user binaries, their documentation, libraries,
>   header files, etc.... X and its supporting libraries can be found
>   here. In current Unices, /usr is where user-land programs and data (as
>   opposed to 'system land' programs and data) are. Some people may now
>   refer to this directory as meaning 'User System Resources' and not
>   'user' as was originally intended. - [TLDP.org](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` is used by the package `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.

If you want to overwrite the configuration, then you **could** use this configuration file. But it will be removed when you delete the package `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` with a `purge` command.

And as you can read in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
```

Use `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and rename the file as noted, but you have to place a number as prefix. By this number the order of processing is affected.

Comment: I don't understand the renaming part. Why renaming ?

Comment: I do not think that renaming is needed. It seems to be more a recommendation.

Comment: The traditional placement for X11 touchpad configuration files is indeed /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/*insert file name here* (the file name does not significantly matter, there are just traditinal filenames like 50-synaptics.conf which would work just as well as touchpad.conf)

Renaming is not needed, but it must have been advised in case the file would find it's way onto a distribution that overwrites the config file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ or something like that, it can probably be ignored on all distros though, since that would be a really bad practice, and I doubt anyone does it.